# jQuery .after() not showing in IE 7

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having a little trouble with a jQuery plugin wrote. I've got it working in every browser I want it to work in (IE 8+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera) but it doesn't work in IE7. Here is the jQuery plugin

```
        (function($) {
        $.fn.popup = function() {
            return this.each(function() {

                $(this).click(function(e){

                    var url = $(this).find('a:eq(0)').attr('href');

                        $('body').after('<div id="pu_bg" class="close"></div>');
                        $('body').after('<div id="pu_content_container">' +
                        '<div id="pu_close_button" class="close"></div>' +
                        '<div id="pu_content">' +
                        'Loading...' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>');
                        $('#pu_bg').height($(document).height());
                        $('#pu_content').load(url);
                        e.preventDefault();

                });

                $('.close').live('click',function() {
                    $('#pu_content_container').hide('slow', function(){
                        $('#pu_bg').fadeOut('fast');
                    });
                });

            });
        }

    })(jQuery);
```

In IE 7 absolutely NOTHING happens. Is there a jQuery function not supported by IE 7? (although I'm sure jQuery is 100% cross browser compatible), have I done something wrong? or is IE7 being fussy and I need to create a work around?

PLEASE HELP! I'm getting really frustrated with this!

Thanks in advance,
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised this works in any browser, since you are trying to append elements after the `body` element. I think you probably want `append` and not `after`.

Comment: ahhh ok, an amateurish mistake. But thanks, fixed the problem! :)